# Call model method from view in Yii2

Tags: view, model, yii2

I want to `call model method` from `view` and listing it in drop-down.

I have Orders model and its method of code below:

```
public function OrderStatus(){
        return [
            ['order_placed', 'Order Placed'],
            ['order_confirm', 'Order Confirm'],
            ['ready_for_delievery', 'Ready For Delivery'],
            ['out_of_delievery', 'Out Of Delivery'],
            ['completed', 'Completed'],
        ];
    }
```

Now I want to fetch above array using method from views of orders and display listing in droddown.

Orders >>  _form View code:

```
<?=
        $order_status = Orders::OrderStatus();
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'order_status')->dropDownList($order_status); ?>
```

But I got error below

```
 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Array to string conversion
```

What actual problem not getting.

Any one have a idea in it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not with your model but with your `$order_status` array. From the API page for [ActiveField::dropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail):

> The array keys are option values, and the array values are the corresponding option labels.

Thus your array should be:

```
public static function OrderStatus(){
    return [
        'order_placed' => 'Order Placed',
        'order_confirm' => 'Order Confirm',
        'ready_for_delievery' => 'Ready For Delivery',
        'out_of_delievery' => 'Out Of Delivery',
        'completed' => 'Completed',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but still same error. My calling method of model method is right?  Orders::OrderStatus();

Comment: The function is meant to be static.